# Parse XML to struct containing slice

Tags: xml, parsing, go, struct, slice

### Situation:

I have this XML structure:

```
<group id="26659127">
    <member ref="292403538"/>
    <member ref="298884289"/>
    <member ref="261728686"/>
    <info k="name" v="omega"/>
    <info k="rank" v="16"/>
</group>
```

I need to convert this XML into this struct:

```
{
    Id: "26659127",
    Members: ["26659127", "298884289", "261728686"],
    Info: [
        {
            Key: "name",
            Value: "omega"
        },
        {
            Key: "rank",
            Value: "16"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Problem:

I created a struct for parsing XML already:

```
type Group struct {
    Id      string   `xml:"id,attr"`
    Members []string `xml:" "`
    Info    []Info   `xml:"info"`
}

type Info struct {
    Key     string   `xml:"k,attr"`
    Value   string   `xml:"v,attr"`
}
```

But, as you can see I haven't defined an expression for `Members` yet. Actually, I tried putting `xml:"member,ref,attr"` and `xml:"member:ref,attr"` in here, but it didn't work.

### Question:

Is there a possibility to solve this issue? If yes, what expression I should use?

Comment: Do it the same way you did with `info`: an array of objects to receive the `member` elements, with those objects having a field to receive the `ref` attribute.

Comment: @Adrian Yea, I know about that. The problem is my database structure requires me to keep it like an array of strings, but not like an array of objects. I know that I can just then iterate through an array of objects and form an array of strings, but in my case it's not the best option (I have around 6,000,000,000 xml documents, so I need to have good speed)

Comment: In terms of performance, iterating a slice of strings is pretty negligible compared to parsing the XML into a struct in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use the default XML unmarshaler to achieve your goal by using only struct field tags so you'll have to either:

1. Extract a struct type for the "Members" field which has a "ref" field (similar to the "Info" type).
2. Use a custom type for "Member" which is a string and implements [`xml.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler) by extracting the value of the "ref" attribute from the associated XML element.

Here is an example of how you can implement strategy #2 above ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/M82C0ViugSd)):

```
type Group struct {
  Id      string      `xml:"id,attr"`
  Members []MemberRef `xml:"member"`
  Info    []Info      `xml:"info"`
}

type MemberRef string

func (m *MemberRef) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
  *m = MemberRef(start.Attr[0].Value) // Assume only the "ref" attribute exists.
  _, err := d.Token() // Consume and discard the synthetic xml.EndElement.
  return err
}

// ...
var group Group
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlstr), &group)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", group)
// main.Group{Id:"26659127", Members:[]main.MemberRef{"292403538", "298884289", "261728686"}, Info:...
```

Note that you can even marshal this struct directly into the example JSON format you listed:

```
bs, err := json.MarshalIndent(group, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(bs))
// {
//   "Id": "26659127",
//   "Members": [
//     "292403538",
//     "298884289",
//     "261728686"
//   ],
//   "Info": [
//     ...
```